# Analytic vector field

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Thank you for providing an explicit definition of an analytic vector field and the intuition behind this notion. I didn't find its definition on the internet.

Can you also provide examples of analytic and non-analytic vector fields? Thank you in advance.